# Opcheckout not detecting checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, jquery-plugins

I am building a e-commerce software and got stuck on payment checkout page.
I have decided to use OP Checkout know as Magento Checkout and included all required JS files. The problem is when i click on Continue button it does not detect which checkbox is ticked. When i debuged to the alert message i found this line of code that needs to catch the user interaction.

```
if ($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) {
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h3>Checkout as a Guest or Register</h3>
  <div class="space10"></div>
  <p>Register with us for future convenience:</p>
  <div class="cbox">
    <input name="checkout_method" id="login:guest" value="guest" class="radio" type="radio"><span for="login:guest">Checkout as Guest</span><br>
    <div class="space10"></div>
    <input name="checkout_method" id="login:register" value="register" class="radio" type="radio"><span for="login:register">Register</span>
  </div>
  <div class="space20"></div>
  <h4>Register and save time!</h4>
  <div class="space10"></div>
  <p>Register with us for future convenience:</p>
  <ul class="ul">
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Fast and easy check out</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Easy access to your order history and status</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="space10"></div>

  <button id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button btn-black" onclick="checkout.setMethod();"><span><span>Continue</span></span></button>
</div>
```

This above code does not catch the result.

Comment: Are `login` and `guest` are classes applied on checkbox?

Comment: You will need to post some html where the login:guest are called.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#`  for `id` selectors and escape `:` from id (Read [Selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)) like,

```
if ($('#login\\:guest').is(':checked')) { //escape : by using \\
```

Another way of using it is,

```
$('[id="login:guest"]').is(':checked');
```

Snippet,

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnCheck').on('click', function() {
    alert($('#login\\:guest').is(':checked') + ',' + $('[id="login:register"]').is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cbox">
  <input name="checkout_method" id="login:guest" value="guest" class="radio" type="radio"><span for="login:guest">Checkout as Guest</span><br>
  <div class="space10"></div>
  <input name="checkout_method" id="login:register" value="register" class="radio" type="radio"><span for="login:register">Register</span>
  <button id="btnCheck">Check</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: guest

Comment: My snippet is working fine, so it should work at your end too, if you have used same code as in my answer.

Comment: On your snippet  you have marked default as checked. You can try your code here it shows false  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=EGaRerfUsR

Comment: I have no idea why but same code above in my browser shows result as false

Answer (score 0):

The code worked after i added .prop('checked') instead of is(':checked');

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnCheck').on('click', function() {
    alert($('#login\\:guest').prop('checked') + ',' + $('[id="login:register"]').prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cbox">
  <input name="checkout_method" id="login:guest" value="guest" class="radio" type="radio"><span for="login:guest">Checkout as Guest</span><br>
  <div class="space10"></div>
  <input name="checkout_method" id="login:register" value="register" class="radio" type="radio"><span for="login:register">Register</span>
  <button id="btnCheck">Check</button>
</div>
```